# When using linkedin share api submitted-picture-url or sharing url via linkedin, particular url format doesnot work?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to share a particular image using Linkedin and also via Linkedin share api, bit the places I see the same problem.

My Url is http://test.actonsoftware.com/acton/cx/812/logo22.png?ts=1427789277713

While sharing this linkedin is unable to load the image. I can see that linkedin hits my server and respond back to linkedin correctly but still it does not show the image.

When using the share from linkedin website I see the same problem.

[image: See the below on Linkedin Website]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem, I was not setting the mime-type for the image. After setting proper mime-type for response header properly it works